# cut method in r with a single number for the breaks argument

Tags: r

I use the `cut` method in R.

```
(cutt <- cut(c(1,5, 10,11, 8,4, 13,2, 3,12, 6,14, 7,15), breaks=2, labels =  FALSE))
```

I expected two groups of equal length. I expected that the numbers get the indices 1 or 2 in an ordered manner ( 1,2,1,2.. OR  1,1,1...2,2,2,.. OR 1,1,2,2,1,1,..)

But the output is

```
 [1] 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

So I got eight times 1 and six times 2. I cannot follow how the mapping works.

Does somebody understand how the cut method distributes the element to the groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading help of cut function. In Rstudio `?cut`.
You can read that the cut function **divides the range of x into intervals and codes the values in x according to which interval they fall. The leftmost interval corresponds to level one, the next leftmost to level two and so on.**

```
x <- c(2, 4, 6)

> cut(x, 3)
[1] (2,3.33]    (3.33,4.67] (4.67,6]   
Levels: (2,3.33] (3.33,4.67] (4.67,6]

> cut(x, 2)
[1] (2,4] (2,4] (4,6]
Levels: (2,4] (4,6]

> levels(cut(x, 2))
[1] "(2,4]" "(4,6]"
```